# How to use derivatives of a function to better estimate its variance over the domain?

Tags: variance, estimation, multivariate-analysis, weighted-sampling, taylor-series

How to use derivatives of a function to better estimate its variance over the domain?

I have a scalar smooth function $f(x)$ and a multivariate random variable $x$ with known distribution (e.g. multivariate standard normal with large diagonal sigma). I know that the function f is very peaky in a sense that for majority of x'es its value rarely deviate from the mean, but on a small subset of x'es it attains extreme values. I need a finite sample estimate of the variance of this function over the domain of X. I can sample x, compute f(x) and use a standard formula, but it seems to be not very efficient since the domain of X is large and high dimensional (hundreds of dimensions) and I know that it is mostly constant.

Intuitively, if I encounter a region with low curvature and "close to the mean" value of f(x), I can "mark" it as "not interesting" and explore the rest of X.

Is there a formal way of doing this? Assume for simplicity that f is antisimmetric so f(x) = -f(-x) so we only need to look for maximas of x. One could probably do something like a variational approximation q such that x' ~ q(x'|x) maximizes expectation of f(x') while being not too far from the standard normal, but this way we have a significant chance of greatly underestimating the variance.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question but it sounds like a direct application of the $\delta$-method.

Comment: @AdamO it is indeed related and the [Taylor expansions for the moments of functions of random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables) seems even more related, but uses an estimate of gradients only at the mean of $X$. I wonder if there's a generalization that 1) uses gradients and values of a function at multiple points $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ 2) says how to choose the next point $x_{n+1}$ to evaluate the gradient and the value of $f(x)$.

Comment: For example, if the function $f(x)$ is fairly flat near $x=0$ but has peaks around $x = \pm \frac{1}{2}$ then delta method would give a bad estimate of $var[f(X)]$ (or it's better to say that the remainder term would be non-negligible because $|| f^{(n)} ||_{\infty}$ are large for large $n$s). The question then is whether we can combine estimates of gradients and values from multiple points to get a better estimate of $var[f(X)]$ and how to choose these points.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was looking for a variant of a [SGLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_Langevin_dynamics) or some other MCMC algorithm that takes gradients into consideration to approximate expectation of a function $f(x)$ when $x \sim P(x)$. I am still not sure how to perform integration when $f(x)$ is complicated, but $P(x)$ is not, I will update the answer when I figure this out.